# Form Summit Issue when we click on the button in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is my code, when I click on the button the form getting submitted and also alignment issues.

```
<button class="variant-button">
    <a href="${test}">
        <span class="variant-button-content">${qualifiers.value}</span>
    </a>
</button>
```

Comment: *"when I click on the button the form getting submitted"* Well...yes. The default `type` of `button` elements is `"submit"`. If you don't want that, use `type="button"`.

Comment: *"also alignment issues"* - Do you really think that's a clear and complete question? Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) (Also note that you should ask **one** question/question, not two or more.)

Comment: your question is not clear and doesn't state any specific problem.

Comment: `<a>` elements may not be descendants of `<button>` elements. Try writing valid HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope the following code will help. Thank you.

```
<a href="${test}">
        <button type="button" class="variant-button">
            <span class="variant-button-content">${qualifiers.value}</span>
        </button>
    </a>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you did, and more importantly, *why*.

Comment: The HTML here is invalid. Don't do that.